# Navigating to C++ function definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for an easy way to find a C++ function definition in Visual Studio Code.

If I search with 'Find in Files' (shift-cmd-F) then it shows me ALL occurrences of the string pattern.  This can sometimes give too many results, thus taking longer to locate the definiton.

I do know about the 'Go To Definition' feature, but that's if you find function symbol references.  But I'm looking for a way to quickly type in the symbol and jump to all known definitions.  I tried Palette Search (cmd-P) and the function definition isn't showing up there either.

I believe emacs has a feature like this.  You would think vscode can do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I found you can use symbol search, which works well only if you know the file to search.

Open the file.  In the editor right-click and select "Go To Symbol In Editor" (<kbd>shift-cmd-O</kbd> on Mac) will open a symbol search and type in the function name.

Arrow down to the function name in the symbol list.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than my other answer.  You can "Go To Symbol In Workspace" (<kbd>cmd-T</kbd> on mac).  Type in the symbol, arrow down to the right one, and hit enter.

I found initially it can take a few seconds to load symbols for a larger project, but subsequent searches for the same symbol are much faster.